# Modifying timed cookie to session

Tags: javascript, jquery, session, cookies

I have a timed cookie that I need to change to a session cookie, I'm not quite sure how to modify it, any help would be appreciated.

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
  } else var expires = "";
  document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like `sessionStorage` may work better for you if you only want to remember the given data for the length of the users visit to your site. It's much simpler to use too.

Comment: You can *always* "replace a cookie."  Not only the value of the cookie but any other attributes will be changed. However, I agree with Rory: "this smells like 'an XY problem.'" Carefully consider what you want to *do,* and look for a simple and effective way to *do* it.  "TMTOWTDI = There's more than one way to do it."